# Can I add a file to rule all: which is not defined in output

Tags: snakemake

A number of commands produce silently extra files not defined in the rule output section.

When I try to make sure these are produced by adding them to 'rule all:' a re-run of the workflow fails because the file are not found in the rule(s) output list.

Can I add a supplementary file (not present as {output}) to the 'rule all:'?

Thanks

eg: STAR index produces a number of files in a folder defined by command arguments, checking for the presence of the folder does not mean that indexing has worked out normally

added for clarity, the STAR index exmple takes 'star_idx_75' as output argument and makes a folder of it in which all the following files are stored (their number may vary in function of the index type).

```
chrLength.txt
chrName.txt
chrNameLength.txt
chrStart.txt
exonGeTrInfo.tab
exonInfo.tab
geneInfo.tab
Genome
genomeParameters.txt
SA
SAindex
sjdbInfo.txt
sjdbList.fromGTF.out.tab
sjdbList.out.tab
transcriptInfo.tab
```

What I wanted was to check that they are all present BUT none of them is used to build the command itself and if I required them in the rule all: a rerun breaks because they are not in any snakemake {output} definition.

This is why I asked wether I could create 'fake' output variables that are not 'used' for running a command but allow placing the corresponding items in the 'rule all:' - am I more clear now :-).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add a supplementary file (not present as {output}) to the 'rule all:'?

I don't think so, at least not without resorting on some convoluted solution. Every file in `rule all` (or more precisely the first rule) must have a rule that lists it in output.

If you don't want to repeat a long list, why not doing something like this?

```
star_index= ['ref.idx1', 'ref.idx2', ...]

rule all:
    input:
        star_index

rule make_index:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        star_index
    shell:
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I meant, I add above more details about the STAR index which is just an example of commands that get one prefix as output argument and use this to produce a folder where a number of files get created

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to list them all in the rule's output, but only use the relevant ones in subsequent rules. You could also look into using `directory()` which could possibly fit here.